# Swift how to show only part of image?

Tags: swift

I have got an image 300px300px, but i only want to show 100x100 of it, just like here https://www.pinterest.com/pin/31103053652400980/ background photo is only showing part of it.How can i do that?

Comment: What's your excuse for not having a tag for development environment?  Mislead people?

Comment: @ElTomato whaaat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UIImageView` that has property **Clip To Bounds** on. After that you can change **Content Mode** of the `UIImageView' that suits you.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You can't imagine how much you helped!

Comment: Which content mode to use exactly?